# macOS Terminal command to test Internet speed

Tags: macos, terminal, network

Anyone know what command can I use to check my Internet speed in the Terminal app?

May be I can use `curl` command and add some IP addresses, like the to check our IP and Country location via `curl ipinfo.io` command?

Comment: Perhaps "system_profiler -listDataTypes". I use this: https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There is a [CLI version of Speedtest](https://github.com/sivel/speedtest-cli) called, appropriately, `speedtest-cli`.

You can install it via Homebrew:

```
brew install speedtest-cli
```

It's also available via [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=speedtest)

Just execute it by running the command:

```
$ speedtest-cli


Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from ACME Cable (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by ServerPronto (Miami, FL) [22.39 km]: 25.419 ms 
Testing download speed............................................................
Download: 70.16 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed............................................................
.Upload: 5.92 Mbit/s
```

Comment: I think this is the simplest method, it doesn't need `sudo` privilege and the command will find nearest server to check the speed. It also display the distance of the server (in Kilometer) with my IP address). 

I'm using VPN, so `Retrieving speedtest.net server list...` and `Selecting best server based on ping...` processes need longer time.

Comment: the command is not `speedtest_cli`, but `speedtest-cli`

Comment: Also available at https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli

Answer (score 28):

If you have **macOS Monterey or later** in your system, here is how you can test Internet speed:-

1. Go to **Terminal**
2. Type `networkQuality -v` and Press **Enter**

You will see internet speed test running inside your terminal & returning the result within a minute.

Sample Output:-

```
==== SUMMARY ====                                                                                         
Upload capacity: 18.856 Mbps
Download capacity: 98.696 Mbps
Upload flows: 20
Download flows: 12
Responsiveness: Low (121 RPM)
Base RTT: 273
Start: 28/11/21, 1:06:09 AM
End: 28/11/21, 1:06:28 AM
OS Version: Version 12.0.1 (Build XXXXXX)
```

(Source: https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT212313)

UPDATED:- In case you are willing to test in **earlier versions of macOS**, just run the following in your terminal.

```
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -
```

Comment: Does networkQuality work in BigSur? I mean, can I copy it to a Big Sur machine and run it?

Comment: @lhf I have updated the answer for earlier macOS versions, kindly try that.

Comment: This is easy and work so good

Answer (score 7):

Install iPerf3 from the developer: [iPerf - The ultimate speed test tool for TCP, UDP and SCTP](https://iperf.fr/iperf-download.php). This is a stand-alone cli, which doesn't require brew or MacPorts.

In the Terminal enter:

```
iperf3 -c <server-ip>
```

to get the upload speed/bandwidth and:

```
iperf3 -c <server-ip> -R
```

to get the download speed/bandwidth

You can get some public iPerf servers here: [Public iPerf3 servers](https://iperf.fr/iperf-servers.php). Other servers are available by searching for iperf/iperf3 servers with Google.

I have tested this one: https://speedtest.wtnet.de/ (while watching TV online) with the following results:

```
iperf3 -c speedtest.wtnet.de -p 5200 -P 10 -4
...
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  12.1 MBytes  10.1 Mbits/sec                  sender
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  10.9 MBytes  9.17 Mbits/sec                  receiver

iperf3 -c speedtest.wtnet.de -p 5200 -P 10 -4 -R
...
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  54.2 MBytes  45.5 Mbits/sec  558             sender
[SUM]   0.00-10.00  sec  51.8 MBytes  43.5 Mbits/sec                  receiver
```

The 558 in the third sum is the number of retransmitted TCP segments (Retr)!

Comment: I've tried @Allan method for this case. But, may this command will be usefule for other user.

Comment: It is available in brew using `brew install iperf`.

Answer (score -1):

Ping and traceroute are legendary unix utilities.

[macworld’s explanation](https://www.google.nl/amp/s/www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac/how-test-ping-on-your-mac-3524076/%3Famp)

TL;DR
ping measures stats about a network path. Your computer/network switch/router/modem is connected to your internet provider/gateway. The gateway has an ip-address xxx.xxx. xxx.xxx, just like your computer and your router. Try

```
sudo time ping -s 1024 -c 1024 xxx.xxx. xxx.xx
```

This will send 1Kilobit 1024 times. Check the total time and do the math. 10 kilobits is roughly 1 kilobyte (due to parity checks).

Comment: How can you measure connection speed with them?

Comment: Well, we'll net scientific calculator after sending this command.