# Terminal Speedtest Script MacOS

Tags: macos, command-line, script, monitoring, ping

I am looking for a Terminal Script for MacOS to monitor my bandwidth and ping etc. like this (linux) ->
https://gitgud.io/J0s3f/speedtest_cron/tree/master

I have the `speedtest-cli` installed via homebrew and I thought it must be possible to do a script that triggers a speed test every 10 minutes and repeats it for example 100 times. After it is finished, it puts the results in a .txt file.

I wanna do the same with a ping that executes e.g. 5 times every 10 Minutes and this for a couple of hours etc and get a results file too.

Background: I am having problems with my internet connection and the ISP call centre guy refusing to see a problem.

Comment: You can ping from the command line from macOS X and before. For example, from the command line just type ping google.com.  You'll have to control c to end because ping -c 10 is not working on my machine but maybe works on yours.  -c 10 is suppose the be numderof times packets ae sent.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but to be more specific i was looking for something to re-do let's say 5 pings every 5 minutes and then put the results into a text file. And the same e.g. for the speedtest-cli that i've installed.

Comment: sorry, i can't help you there.

Comment: There are two questions here - how to use *speedtest-cli* and a script to monitor bandwidth whims is a bit broad.  Take a look at [this answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/317552/macos-terminal-command-to-test-internet-speed/317564#317564) for the first and possibly explain how it doesn’t solve your problem or what more you’re looking for

Comment: @ankiiiiiii Hi, thank you for your help. I edited the question.

Comment: @Allan Hi, thank you for your help. I edited the question.

Comment: Can‘t you just use the code from the github repository you link in your question?

Comment: @nohillside Thanks, i just figured it out by learning a bit scripting today

Comment: Feel free to post your code as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Background: I am having problems with my internet connection and the ISP call centre guy refusing to see a problem.

This is key to understanding your problem question.  What is the problem *exactly* that you’re are experiencing?  Going into detail here will help you (help us) come up with a solution that addresses your exact problem.

From your question, it seems that you are attempting to utilize (at least) two tools to determine what the issue is.  The problem is, neither tool is sufficient to get you accurate metrics to help you diagnose the perceived problem.

#### Ping

Ping measures how fast your network adapter responds to a request (a.k.a. Latency).   The problem with this is that you can have lightening fast latency (i.e. 10ms), but horrible bandwidth (56Kpbs) to transfer your files.

Where ping will come in handy is monitoring this latency over time assuming latency is the issue you're experiencing.

#### Bandwidth

You may have and pay for a high speed connection from your ISP, but what happens outside your ISP’s network could be the issue here.  See the post [Improve file transfer performance over VPN](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348841/119271) for more details on this.  Basically, if the tech at your ISP is measuring data transfer rates from the ISP to your site it may be working fine (which is all the ISP is responsible for).

It’s entirely possible a server on a different network has a low bandwidth connection is creating the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your time but i was looking for a script to do two specific things and nothing else. I sat down and figured it out today by getting my head around on how to do a bit of scripting wich was really not that hard. i am sorry for beeing lazy i should've done that in the first place instead of this here.